# Как прибавить значение, но чтобы оно стало не больше максимального?

Tags: php, разработка-игр

Делаю игру с персонажем Целителем. Вот основы:

- `$_SESSION[regen]=5` - это код количества восстановления хп. (Целитель восстанавливает 5хп.)
- `$udata[hp]` - это код, который отображает, сколько у меня хп. (Пусть будет например 10хп.)
- `$udata[hpall]` - это отображение максимального количества хп.

То есть, нужно сделать ссылку "Исцелиться", при нажатии на нее, к моему хп прибавляется 5хп. Но если мои жизни полные, мне должно вывести надпись "Вы здоровы".

Answer (score 2):

```
if($udata[hp] < $udata[hpall]){
    $udata[hp] = $udata[hp]+$_SESSION[regen];
    if($udata[hp] > $udata[hpall]){
        $udata[hp] = $udata[hpall];
    }
    echo "Игрок исцелен!";
}else{
    echo "Игрока исцелять не нужно, у него полно здоровья!";
}
```

Мой велосипед %)

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
$fullHpMsg = 'Вы полностью исцелены';
if($udata[hp] < $udata[hpall]) { 
    $udata[hp] = $udata[hp]+$_SESSION[regen] < $udata[hpall] ? $udata[hp]+$_SESSION[regen] : $udata[hp] = $udata[hpall];

    $message = 'Целитель вылечил ' . $_SESSION[regen] . ' hp';
    $message .= "\n" . 'Теперь у вас ' . $udata[hp] . ' hp';
    if($udata[hp] == $udata[hpall]) {
         $message .= "\n" . $fullHpMsg;
    }
    echo $message;
}
else {
     echo $fullHpMsg;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Вообще:

```
if $udata[hp] = $udata[hpall] then echo Жизни полны else Прибавление
```

Извини, что не написал весь код, я не знаю php

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($udata[hp] == $udata[hpall])
echo "Вы здоровы";
else
{
$udata[hp] = $_SESSION[regen];
echo "Лечение завершено";
}
?>
```

Comment: А если у него будет 9/10 hp, прибавится 5 hp, и у него будет 14/10 hp?

в моем варианте это учтено

Comment: Опять не верно)

Если у игрока будет 9/10 хп, то после вашего лечения у него станет 5/10 хп. То есть хп наоборот уменьшится)

Comment: Ахах... Кароче играю я, у меня 50hp, всегодолжно быть 100... Решил пойти к целителю, целитель сливает мне хп до 5и еще и злорадствует - лечение завершено :DDD

Comment: @AlexWindHope о чем я и говорил :D